# LaTeX link error using href inside of tabular block

Tags: pdf, url, latex, href, pdflatex

I have this LaTeX code:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l} \small MY ADDRESS\\
\href{http://www.github.com}{github} \end{tabular}
```

Which is giving me this error and no other details...

```
Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \href 

l.27 \href
         {http://www.github.com}{github} \end{tabular}
```

does anyone know why??

Comment: backslash is a control char, perhaps you meant to use `\url` instead of `\href`

Comment: \url gives me the same error... @karakfa

Comment: Please post a [MCVE.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @yacc this is an MCVE...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load the [`hyperref` package](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) in order to use `\href{<url>}{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
  \small MY ADDRESS \\
  \href{http://www.github.com}{github}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```